# Error on a percentile star graph (probably syntax)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have edited three different NotePad documents for a quiz that will be used in the upcoming school year. The main use for this is he tester answers radio buttons that come out as percentages at the end of the quiz when you push the button "update at the bottom. In the first note it was making a star graph with five spikes according to the percent of choice percentages applied (at least 2 percent #s per tooth of graph). When I ran the code that made the graph by itself it worked fine, but when I copied the piece that made the graph into the quiz code it wold have an error in the note it was taking from. "clarkquiz" had things pasted from "Quiztaker" that had a function that ran "jsgl-min" and "Quiztaker" worked fine alone, but "clarkquiz" did not. it would say there is an error in "jsgl_min" which there's not. right now its just supposed to make two pentagons- one smaller than the other and inside the bigger one.

---

```
  /* This is the part i want to paste */
  var tinypolygon = myPanel.createPolygon();
  /*   for(b=0;b<360;b=b+360/5){
  tinypolygon.addPointXY(50*Math.cos(b*3.14159/180)+320,50*Math.sin(b*3.14159/180)+240);
 }
  polygon = myPanel.createPolygon();
  for(a=0;a<360;a=a+360/5){
  polygon.addPointXY(200*Math.cos(a*3.14159/180)+320,200*Math.sin(a*3.14159/180)+240);
 }
  tinypolygon.getStroke().setWeight(2);
  tinypolygon.getStroke().setColor("rgb(0,0,150)");
  tinypolygon.getFill().setColor("rgb(0,500,0)");
  tinypolygon.getFill().setOpacity(0.2);
  myPanel.addElement(tinypolygon);

  polygon.getStroke().setWeight(2);
  polygon.getStroke().setColor("rgb(0,0,255)");
  polygon.getFill().setColor("rgb(0,255,0)");
  polygon.getFill().setOpacity(0.2);*/
  myPanel.addElement(tinypolygon);

  /*This part is what is causing the problem*/
  var teamAvg = Math.round(Math.mean(habit3Percent,habit9Percent,habit15Percent));
  var createAvg = Math.round(Math.mean(habit11Percent,habit4Percent));
  var reflectAvg = Math.round(Math.mean(habit5Percent,habit2Percent,habit12Percent,habit8Percent));
  var critAvg = Math.round(Math.mean(habit7Percent,habit6Percent));
  var exploAvg = Math.round(Math.mean(habit13Percent,habit10Percent,habit16Percent));




  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

```
  var teamAvg = Math.round((habit3Percent+habit9Percent+habit15Percent)/3);
  var createAvg = Math.round((habit11Percent+habit4Percent)/2);
  var reflectAvg =     Math.round((habit5Percent+habit2Percent+habit12Percent+habit8Percent)/4);
  var critAvg = Math.round((habit7Percent+habit6Percent)/2);
  var exploAvg = Math.round((habit13Percent+habit10Percent+habit16Percent)/3); 

var makeButtons = function(questionID,buttonName){
document.getElementById(questionID).innerHTML="Most of the time<input type='radio'     name='"+buttonName+"' value=3><br>Some of the time<input type='radio' name='"+buttonName+"'     value=2><br>Rarely<input type='radio' name='"+buttonName+"' value=1><br>Never<input     type='radio' name='"+buttonName+"' value=0 checked><br><br><br>";
}

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a debugging service. Please trim your code down to the smallest possible bit that demonstrates the problem, and if you don't see it yourself then ask again.

Comment: ok, thanks for telling me, I cut a lot out, so I think that's whats making things not work.